# browser doesn't show received socket data immediately

Tags: php, sockets, browser

```
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 100);
socket_listen($socket);
$client = socket_accept($socket);
socket_write($client, 'output');
sleep(10);
socket_close($client);
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

When I go to the terminal and type `nc localhost 100` I get *output* immediately, as I want.
But when I type "`localhost:100`" in the address bar in the browser, the word *output* is showed up after 10 seconds.

**But!**
If I change the code to:

```
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 100);
socket_listen($socket);
$client = socket_accept($socket);
$str = '';
for ($index = 0; $index < 4096; $index++) {
    $str .= ' ';
}
socket_write($client, $str);
socket_write($client, 'output');
sleep(10);
socket_close($client);
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

I get *output* (and all the spaces before it) on the browser immediately after sending the request.

How can I get the *output* immediately in the browser without sending a lot of data?

Comment: WHy do you have the sleep 10 in your code?

Comment: Just for the example.
I have a script that writes to sockets, the script has while(true) in it, so it's execution does not end quickly, and the output is showed up in the browser after the execution is ended.

Comment: Your code writes to the socket, not reads from it, I dont see how you would get your socket output anyway

Comment: It listens to connections, when a connection is made (socket_accept), I write to this connected socket. The reading is done in the other side. If I run in the terminal `nc localhost 100` I get "output" back. The problem is when I go to `localhost:100` in the browser. In the browser I see the output only after the script is ended (unless I send spaces, as I showed in the question).

Comment: Most likely you see differences because your telnet app negotiates differences for you. As I said, from the code above, I dont see how your browser would ever see anything as from memory, nothing there is pulling text back to show on screen. If you 're just "sending" data, send and close. Dont do the wait.

Comment: But if i run `nc localhost 100` on terminal I do get "output". Also, if I write many spaces, the browser shows it (check the second code in the original question).

Comment: OK, I dont see how any of your output ends in your browser, perhaps there is other code you havent listed. Your socket may accept data, and send it, but its not been told to read it or do anything with it.. If you get "output" when you run it .. Your second code which is supposedly listening, is not READING data its also told to write it, nothing on either code says "read stuff from socket and display it"

Comment: Take a look here: [link](http://oi46.tinypic.com/2wod9gx.jpg).

Comment: Cant, its blocked - as Im at work

Comment: Try [link](http://i46.tinypic.com/2wod9gx.jpg), or [link](http://tinypic.com/r/2wod9gx/6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is the output buffering of PHP, that is possibly enabled. Flush the buffer as described by Samyam A. Or disable it by using: using ob_end_flush();
2. The browser itself may ignore data, until it's over some limit (~1KB) or the connection was closed. This is due to some optimization. They assumed that the first 1KB of a document doesn't have enough useful information to render a preview of a document. Solution: Send 1KB of dummy data (e.g. whitespaces) at the beginning. Then send data as normal.
3. There are possibilies that there is a virus scanner or a toolbar that acts as a proxy server which handles HTTP streams in a way that it first fetches a complete block of data (or even the whole document) and when done they process and forward that block. This should not happen, if you work at port 100 (which is a usual trick to prevent such tools from delaying the data stream). More over you work at localhost. If you do have an internet provider between (especially mobile network operators), you'll possibly have your data tunneled through a transparent proxy server, which causes such problems too.

Comment: I guess it's because the browser (2)... I will send some spaces. I was sure that there is a solution which doesn't include sending spaces, but maybe there isn't. Thanks.

Comment: You can try 'chunked encoding', to avoid this 1KB data. But I'm unsure if this will help against the browser ignoring data until first 1 KB of data received. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Answer (score 2):

You might be seeing this behaviour since in your first case, the data you are sending is too small and thus the output buffer might be keeping it around till enough data is filled or the connection is closed.

try flushing the data using `ob_implicit_flush()` or calling `ob_flush()` explicitly after each write:

```
<?php
ob_implicit_flush();
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 100);
socket_listen($socket);
$client = socket_accept($socket);
socket_write($client, 'output');
sleep(10);
socket_close($client);
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Comment: One also could disable the output buffer e.g. `using ob_end_flush();`. This avoids flushing the buffer over and over again.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. The browser still "waits" 10 seconds before showing the output.